# How To Ban Certain Words And Then Delete Messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

What my goal is to check a users input in a discord channel contains a certain word or phrase that i have in a list, that looks like this:

```
illegal_words = ["apple", "pear", "banana"]
```

The expected outcome is to when what i type contains one or more of the following words that it sees the word, then deletes, and then afterwards sends a message that says that you are not allowed to type that specific message.

This is my current code with the list included

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="..")

illegal_words = ["apple", "pear", "banana"]

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    [word in message.content for word in illegal_words]
    any([word in message.content for word in illegal_words])
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send("""That Word Is Not Allowed To Be Used!
    Continued Use Of Mentioned Word Would Lead To Punishment!""")
```

Comment: no profanities in your chat...but here? why not substitute it with fruits to make it a nicer example? Also - dont need 50 , 3or 4 would be fine for an example. And then please prepare a [mre] that we can run. Your method does not contain any ifs  ... you create a list just to throw it away and create a bool to throw it away as well.

Comment: Sorry for the negative example, i can change it :)

Comment: Careful with the generic `in` check or users will have a hard time talking about s**hell**s, or anything sp**arse**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if any(word in message.content for word in illegal_words):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("""That Word Is Not Allowed To Be Used! Continued Use Of Mentioned Word Would Lead To Punishment!""")
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

`on_message` receives a `Message` object, not a `Context`.  We can delete the message directly, and should respond to it by sending messages to the channel it is in.

Comment: Won't using `in` lead to some issues, since it's not matching entire words at a time?

Comment: @AMC Maybe.  You could probably solve that with something like regex search for `\bword\b` for each word.  That leads to it's own problems though, as it's easier to get around.